# How to call third patry API in convers of WIT.AI?

Tags: ajax, wit.ai

I am facing trouble to call or fetch third party API for wit.ai.
How can i make AJAX call to fetch "weather" information and bind it to converse method. 
In image context - wit.ai story fetchWeather(context) method. How to connect with ajax call to specific method for weather output.

[FetchWeather(context)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOG55.png)

Answer (score 0):

so in NodeJs you can use callbacks or Promises to chain you're petitions.

Wit.ai has actions defined by yourself, each time Wit.ai send a messages, it calls the send action, but if you defined an action in your story, then all processes should be done inside that specific action (because it is execute before send action) [image]

In the image above you can see my action named getFullName, inside there I chain promises to query the user name and then build the fullNameGreeting to insert in my context.

If you have any question, you should read the wit.ai tutorial and download the an implement version for Node or Python. https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart